# jQuery Trigger on Element Load Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, single-page-application

I'm working with a single page application.

On the last step, I want to trigger an event based on an element that loads on the final step of the SPA.

When I use a function like this:

```
if ($('.order_details.curve_panel').length >=1) {

alert('it worked');

}
```

It works...in the console after the element has loaded. But, when I insert the code into the HTML it doesn't actually trigger the event (in this case the alert).

But, when I use the .load method nothing

```
$('.order_details.curve_panel').load(function() {

alert('it worked');

});
```

Am I missing something? Is the SPA causing this issue and is there a method I could use to make the event trigger as SOON as the element is loaded?

Below is an example of the HTML. "class = "order_details curve_panel" does not appear until the last step of my SPA. It is NOT loading on a page load as it is part of a Single Page Application. It loads only after the user proceeds to the final step of the SPA. At the time of page load, it is not available.

```
<div class="order_details curve_panel">
   <div class="shiptoexpanded">
      <div>3 / 15</div>
      <div group-key="Shipping 12/2/2020">
         <div class="shipSort">20201202</div>
         12/2/2020
      </div>
      <div group-key="">$53.11</div>
      <div group-key="">$159.33</div>
      <div group-key="">$11.10</div>
      <div group-key="">$170.43</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When this appears, I need to trigger an event...for now I am just trying to trigger an alert.

Comment: Are you confusing the `.load()` shorthand method for ajax and the load event? Try `$('.order_details.curve_panel').on("load", function() {`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, quite possibly I am confusing it. I'll try really quick. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, doesn't look like it works. I believe this is due to the fact that the elements aren't available at the time the "screen" loads since it's a Single Page Application. I believe the code is running before the elements are available so when they do become available it is not triggering.   Per the .on documentation:  "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup"

Comment: Okay... Then try with delegation: `$(window).on("load", ".order_details.curve_panel", function() {` I will post an answer if that works.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, :( looks like a no go. But, I appreciate the ideas. Not really sure what it could be at this point.

Comment: So the `load` event is not what you need. What makes `.order_details.curve_panel` appear? Scrolling? Just for fun, try `$(body).on("scroll", function(){ if ($('.order_details.curve_panel').length >=1) { console.log("OK") }}) `

Comment: Please make an [mcve] of the issue.  Keeping in mind that most HTML Elements will not receive a `load` event.  `window`, iframes, images, other media tags, they will get load events.  Your basic page structuring tags will not.  And `load` events do not bubble.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette delegates don't work with load as load does not bubble.

Comment: @Taplar, Added the MRE

Comment: Yeah, `<div>`s don't have load events

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the .load from jquery does but maybe you have to use a mutation observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Hopefully that will help you!

Ok I don't know why i got the -1 but maybe i have to explain a little bit more:

1. this is a single page application so the load event on the whole page does not make sense as the javascript can still add elements to the DOM
2. if you try your code

```js
$('.order_details.curve_panel').load(function() {

alert('it worked');

});
```

and the element does not exist at that time $('.order_details.curve_panel') can not find anything.

That is why you need a mutation observer to check if the element has been added and then react on it

Comment: Got rid of that -1 for you. Your original answer is perfectly acceptable to me. Mutation is probably the best thing to observe in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use your script, when the page loaded all DOM elements

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
   if ($('.order_details.curve_panel').length >=1) {
      alert('it worked');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. The code needs to continually check for the element since it is made available AFTER page load on a single page application. Using the
setInterval and clearInterval, I was able to accomplish the trigger.

```
(function(d) {
    var interval;

    function check() {

        if ($('.order_details.curve_panel').length >= 1) {
            alert('it worked');

            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
    interval = setInterval(check, 100); // duration: 100ms
}(document));
```